# .NET Core API using Microsoft Identity Platform returns 200 when OIDC access token has expired

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-platform

I have created an API in .NET Core, and I am using Microsoft Identity Platform for authentication. Everything works fine, but when my access token has expired my methods still return http status 200, but with no result, but I would expect them to return 401 instead.

In the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class I initialize the authentication by adding this line:

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration);
```

And in the Configure method I call `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()`. Finally, in the controller the methods use the Authorize attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
```

So, when making a call to the Get method using an expired bearer token, I would expect the method to return a 401, but I get a 200 with no result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the order of the middleware was the problem. I had put a call to a custom middleware between `app.UseAuthentication()` and `app.UseAuthorization()` that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell for Microsoft identity but in other identity providers you should have something like

```
services.AddAuthentication("OIDC")
                .AddJwtBearer("OIDC",
                                options =>
                                {
                                    options.Authority = authority;
                                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                                                                    {
                                                                        ValidateAudience = true,
                                                                        ValidAudiences = validAudiences,
                                                                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                                                                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                                                                        ValidIssuer = validIssuer,
                                                                        NameClaimType = "user",
                                                                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
                                                                    };
                                });
```

Notice there is a ValidateLifeTime in TokenValidationParameters
property which must be set to true

See also [What exact token validation is done by Microsoft.Identity.Web’s aspnet core middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71076252/what-exact-token-validation-is-done-by-microsoft-identity-web-s-aspnet-core-midd)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried different variants of this, but with no success. Specifically, I set ValidateLifeTime to true (it should be set to that default though).

Comment: @OskarLundgren  in wich order do you call app.UseAuthentication(); and  app.UseAuthorization(); ? It should be called  before app.UseEndpoints(), not after

Comment: Thank you! This led me to find the culprit (see accepted answer).